# Force Closure of a channel with LNBig-42:

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing, ln-closing-channels

On May 14th our channel with LNBIG-42 was force closed. Not sure why but it could have been due to their node performing an update on the same day which caused a few other nodes to also have their channels force closed. Our channel force closure is still pending but I am hopeful that it will be resolved soon as it has only been about a week. Any ideas you can glean from the mempool's transactions below will help considerably as we are hoping our side does not get hit with a large sat fee for the forced closure as I do not believe our node initiated the close

mempool transaction:

https://mempool.space/tx/c75f38d1a86b0878d2b38198c17683cd4b6a10e2eea2d031ec085e25d1862149:1

mempool closing transaction:

https://mempool.space/tx/93b1caa7fd098d9fb5c10bc3d800d0fa71a9332396a6d85262cf99b5fc021839

Answer (score 0):

> Our channel force closure is still pending but I am hopeful that it will be resolved soon as it has only been about a week.

Keep an eye on the status of the force close and check to make sure it happens on schedule. If it is not happening on schedule and it was initiated from your node, you can reach out to the operator of LNBig-42 and ask them to initiate a force-close from their side.

Otherwise it was initiated from their node and you may be able to use this: https://www.reddit.com/r/lightningnetwork/comments/nblv5d/can_you_forceclose_a_channel_that_is_already/ to force close from your side, but I cannot be sure because in this thread the channel close was mutual.

This was likely caused by the same HTLC expiration default setting observed in this question posted a few days ago:
[Automatic force closure and on chain settlement of expired HTLC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118364/automatic-force-closure-and-on-chain-settlement-of-expired-htlc)

Comment: Hi Poseidon,Thanks for the info it is most appreciated. I saw that node LNBig-42's HTLC settings were 80 were ours was 40 is that usual? We are disappointed because LNBig-42 was one of the main reasons we were doing so much routing of sats and now it has slowed to a flea's crawl. What can we do to prevent this in the future? Thank you :)

Comment: @Orange_Bitcoin I can't speak to whether or not it is usual. Assuming you are talking about the hours before a channel is force closed due to HTLC expiration, there is nothing obviously wrong with them giving you twice as much time as you would give them, in fact that would represent more willingness on their part to wait for you to fix downtime issues. Did you notice that the node was down during this period?

Comment: Hi Poseidon, Our node was not down during this period but I did check their Amboss page at the closed transactions and there were 3 others that had been force closed round about the same time period. Also I saw on cheeserobot that they had peformed an update to their node on the same day as our force closure so I suppose that may have had a lot to do with it. Thank you again. :)